# Nginx condition proxy based on the $request_body

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want my server proxy `Google` if my `$request_body` of a `POSTed` request contains the string `google`, e.g.

```
echo "google" | lwp-request -m POST "http://127.0.0.1"
```

So I have the config like, e.g.

```
server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:80 default;

  location / {
        if ($request_body ~* .*google.*) {
            proxy_pass http://www.google.com;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But the result of the above config is always **"404 Not Found"**

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it is your nginx that returns the 404, and not the proxied request?

Comment: @pkhamre, the 404 is returned from `nginx`, I can see the at the footer `<hr><center>nginx/1.1.19</center>`